# How do you set up the Nuclide debugger?

Tags: atom-editor, javascript-debugger, nuclide-editor

I'm using the Nuclide (Atom package for React Native development) to check logs and to set breakpoints. So far it has worked great in the Chrome debugger, but I would love to see if I can get Nuclide to work as well (so it's all in the IDE).

1) I attached the debugger:
[image]

2) When I manually write the `debugger` command in the code, it will pause it and show the call stack within the Nuclide panel in Atom, but unfortunately the sourcemaps are messed up and are showing the bundle. It looks like the bundle is in the default location, so I shouldn't need to set up anything for that, but I must be missing something.
[image]

3. Another problem I'm experiencing is that I can't set breakpoints in the IDE since it is showing as unresolved breakpoints, which means it is a breakpoint on code that is not part of the project on which the debugger process is attached, although it seems to me like I set it up all correctly.
   [image]

If anybody has any ideas why these things are not working, please let me know.